# How do I setup Mockery to return values based on previous method calls?

Tags: laravel, testing, mockery, php-pest

I'm using Laravel, Pest for my tests and Mockery for mocking. I have a simple action that looks like so:

```
public function handle(): array
{
    $sites = [];

    $envDir = dirname(__FILE__, 3).'/env';
    $envFiles = File::glob($envDir.'/.env.*');

    foreach ($envFiles as $envFile) {
        $basename = basename($envFile);
        $site = str_replace('.env.', '', $basename);
        $dotenv = Dotenv::createArrayBacked(dirname($envFile), $basename)
            ->safeLoad();

        if (! isset($dotenv['APP_URL'])) {
            throw new Exception('Missing APP_URL in ' . $basename);
        }

        $sites[$site] = rtrim($dotenv['APP_URL'], '/');
    }

    return $sites;
}
```

The code loads several `.env.[whatever]` files and grabs the `APP_URL` parameter. It works fine, but I want to write a test.

For the `File` facade, I simply use `File::shouldReceive()`, etc, and that works great.

I am now trying to mock the `Dotenv` requirement. I know that I will have to create it from the container (or inject it), but I'm not sure how to do so using `createArrayBacked` passing different parameters. Is that even possible?

And once that's setup, I can't figure out how to mock it. If someone sends a specific path and filename to `createArrayBacked`, then `safeLoad()` is called, then on the resulting array `APP_URL` is accessed, I want to provide a specific value based on those original parameters passed to `createArrayBacked`.

Comment: I do not follow what you want, could you add the test and an example please?

Comment: I would not mock `DotEnv` but fake a file, so when it is read, it reads the fake data I put, and I expect to get that back, so no need to mock anything. Did you try that?